# Numeric sort of list of dictionary objects

Tags: python, sorting, numeric, alphanumeric

I am very new to python programming and have yet to buy a textbook on the matter (I am buying one from the store or Amazon today).  In the meantime, can you help me with the following problem I have encountered?

I have an list of dictionary objects like this:

```
stock = [ 
  { 'date': '2012', 'amount': '1.45', 'type': 'one'},
  { 'date': '2012', 'amount': '1.4', 'type': 'two'},
  { 'date': '2011', 'amount': '1.35', 'type': 'three'},
  { 'date': '2012', 'amount': '1.35', 'type': 'four'}
]
```

I would like to sort the list by the amount date column and then by the amount column so that the sorted list looks like this:

```
stock = [ 
  { 'date': '2011', 'amount': '1.35', 'type': 'three'},
  { 'date': '2012', 'amount': '1.35', 'type': 'four'},
  { 'date': '2012', 'amount': '1.4', 'type': 'two'},
  { 'date': '2012', 'amount': '1.45', 'type': 'one'}
]
```

I now think I need to use sorted() but as a beginner I am having difficulties understanding to concepts I see.

I tried this:

```
from operator import itemgetter
all_amounts = itemgetter("amount")
stock.sort(key = all_amounts)
```

but this resulted in an list that was sorted alphanumerically rather than numerically.

Can someone please tell me how to achieve this seemingly simple sort?  Thank-you!

Comment: Why don't you just convert the data in your dict into numbers?  It seems like that would be a better representation.

Comment: Your `stock` isn't valid Python. Please fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sorting condition is too complicated for an `operator.itemgetter`. You will have to use a lambda function:

```
stock.sort(key=lambda x: (int(x['date']), float(x['amount'])))
```

or

```
all_amounts = lambda x: (int(x['date']), float(x['amount']))
stock.sort(key=all_amounts)
```

Comment: Wow!  That was super quick and exactly what I needed.  Thank-you eumiro, I will spend the next hour trying to work out what it all means :-)

Comment: Just try `all_amounts[stock[0]]` and see how it builds a tuple to sort .

Answer (score 1):

Start by converting your data into a proper format:

```
stock = [
    { 'date': int(x['date']), 'amount': float(x['amount']), 'type': x['type']}
    for x in stock
]
```

Now `stock.sort(key=all_amounts)` will return correct results.

As you appear to be new in programming, here's a word of general advice if I may:

> Proper data structure is 90 percent of success. Do not try to work around broken data by writing more code. Create a structure adequate to your task and write as less code as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the fact that python's sort is [stable](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#Sort_Stability_and_Complex_Sorts):

```
stock.sort(key=lambda x: int(x["amount"]))
stock.sort(key=lambda x: int(x["date"]))
```

Since the items with the same key keep their relative positions when sorting (they're never swapped), you can build up a complicated sort by sorting multiple times.